# Selecting multiple partial field contents using ArcGIS Select By Attribute?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql, select-by-attribute, arcgis-10.6

I can't seem to get the hang of ArcGIS Select By Attributes SQL. I'm trying to "select all that contain Street and Road and etc." Working with polyline SHP.

This works:

```
"NAME" LIKE ('%Street%')
```

This doesn't:

```
"NAME" LIKE ('%Street%', '%Road%')
```

Comment: `"NAME" LIKE '%Street% OR "NAME" LIKE '%Road%`. I dont think what you are trying is possible see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014940/is-there-a-combination-of-like-and-in-in-sql

Comment: Thanks @BERA. That worked (though I added the close '). I was hoping the cleaner way would work based on https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000009011 , but so it goes. If you type it up, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This should work:**

```
"NAME" LIKE ('%Street%') OR "NAME" LIKE ('%Road%')
```

Comment: I agree that your answer will help the OP answer the question, but I wanted to add that the parentheticals should not be required in this instance.

Comment: @Rob,  True enough, it would be nice if this command would work, but obviously the % wildcard doesn't work in conjunction with the IN operator but % wildcard works only when the LIKE operator is used.